# How to implement router animation in Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I want to have some animation when navigating between pages in Blazor

How can I implement router animation in the Blazor app?

Comment: Consider looking at the repo and package which was designed to do just that at https://github.com/JByfordRew/BlazorTransitionableRoute

Answer (score 4):

Currently no such feature is supported in Blazor. The Router system in Blazor provides very limited functionality compared to, say, Angular. Be patient. Its coming. Meanwhile you may implement router animation by creating a custom router system of yourself. See articles by chris sainty how to do it. [This...](https://chrissainty.com/an-in-depth-look-at-routing-in-blazor/) and [that...](https://chrissainty.com/building-a-custom-router-for-blazor/)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hey Enet, was searching for something about animating routing. Was there any progress in that topic?

Answer (score 1):

I created this repo and nuget package to do just that at https://github.com/JByfordRew/BlazorTransitionableRoute

This is the 'how it works' section

"Having two view layouts means we can remember the previous route but we cannot simply overwrite them, they must be preserved so we do not lose browser state like scroll position etc. This solution handles the route views and knows when to call the transition implementation you provide to it. It also works with the browser navigation buttons. If you need to handle in app back buttons then use the jsInterop to call the native back i.e. window.history.back(); This is as simple a solution I could arrive at. If there is another simpler one please let me know."

Comment: This is AMAZING and it seems to work flawlessly on Blazor MAUI in Chrome and Android, however on iOS, it crashes on creating Main.  Would really be amazing if you could update your code to support iOS too and maybe MacCatalyst? Please!!!!!!!  Such a good piece of work you have there!

Comment: @CookieMonster really appreciate your comment. Unfortunately I do not have access to Apple hardware. Please reach out to others or yourself to create a Pull Request. I will certainly reach out also.

Comment: I would love to have the skills and knowledge on how to even go about fixing this issue.  Maybe one day I'll be good enough!  Not sure if this will help, but with the latest version of visual studio you no longer need a Mac build host.  Just plug your iPhone straight into your Windows PC and you can deploy!

Answer (score -1):

I have a Nuget package called DataJuggler.Blazor.Components, and one of the two components in it so far is called a Sprite.

Here is the source code including a sample project:

https://github.com/DataJuggler/DataJuggler.Blazor.Components

Here is a video:

https://youtu.be/frtetHgfdIo

Here is a sample of using the component

@using DataJuggler.Blazor.Components

```
<Sprite ImageUrl="../images/WhiteCar.png" Name="WhiteCar" Position="fixed"
    Height="30" Subscriber=this Width="96" ZIndex="10" 
    XPosition="@WhiteCarPosition" YPosition="@WhiteCarY"
    Scale="1.4">
</Sprite>
```

If you look at the part that says Subscriber=this, your parent page or component must be implement interface  DataJuggler.Blazor.Components.Interfaces.ISpriteSubscriber

It just sets a few properties which all you to talk from your parent to the child, and vice versa.

My sample project uses BlazorStyled by Chanan, which allows me to dynamically change CSS values to update the XPosition value for each Sprite (I show a race of two cars as a demo)

The sprite components contains a Timer, so you can start a Sprite by calling:

```
// I only start 1 timer, and I handle both cars movement on each Timer tick.
redCar.Start();
```

There is a property for Interval, so set it to the speed that works best for you.

I have another project started called BlazorAnimation, but I can only work on 7 or 8 projects at a time.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I found repo for that https://github.com/mikoskinen/Blazor.Animate  but I can't use this feature for animate routing. my target is to implement routing animation

Comment: I don't understand what routing animation means. You want something to display as pages change?

Comment: I just learned what Routing Animation is, but you could do this with BlazorStyled, you would have to handle the routing yourself:

Here is a document about Routing for Blazor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1